# In hight chart how can i show yAxis value on xAxis?

Tags: c#, highcharts

```
.SetXAxis(new XAxis
     {
         Categories = xyzList.ToArray(),
         Labels = new XAxisLabels
         {
             //  Formatter = "function() { return this.labels; }",
             Style = "color: 'Black',fontSize: '10px',fontFamily: 'Arial'",
             UseHTML = true,
             //formatter with image is 
             Formatter = "function() { return '<div class=\"ImageDiv\" style=\"height:25px; background-image:url(../../Themes/Images/'+ this.value+'.jpg)\"/>';}",
            // Formatter = "function() { return this.y;}",

         }

     })
```

i want to display YAxis value in to xAsix but it shows undefined.
 **How can i access YAxis value on the XAXis?**

[image]

Comment: Hey!!!!! there is any one who know about this????

Comment: As I can see you are using some wrapper for Highcharts, so my knowledge will be limited, but what do you mean yAxis value on xAxis? That doesn't have much sense.. maybe you want to display point's value? Be more specific please. PS: Don't be rude.

Comment: @PawełFus i am using `highchart.dll` for development. YAxis value means i want to show the same value as data on the x axis.

Comment: Okay, then: remove formatter which you are actually using. Then set categories to ve the same as values for a chart (`Categories = xyzList.ToArray(),` - that line need to be changed.

Comment: @PawełFus : i can't remove existing categories, because i am showing the logos from that name at the bottom as shown in black :(.

Comment: So you want to **add** value below LOGO? Then when you set that logo add info about x value, that's all. `xyzList` should contain `<img logo> <br> value`.

Comment: @PawełFus : i have changed the `formatter` in above code please check that. here this.value return that `category` name same as i need point value? what should i use? `this.y` is not working here.

Comment: `this` is pointing to the category, not to the point object. You can have multiple points per one category.

Comment: why -1?? any reason for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on data format you are using. Possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1036/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['01/02/2012', '01/03/2012', '01/04/2012', '01/05/2012', '01/06/2012', '01/07/2012'],
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var index = this.axis.categories.indexOf(this.value);
                var points = this.axis.series[0].options.data;
                return points[index];
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]
    }]
});
```

Comment: `this.axis.series[0].options.data[this.axis.categories.indexOf(this.value)]` replace this in above question and it worked !!!! thanks a lot dude. `Formatter = "function() { return '<div class=\"ImageDiv\" style=\"background-image:url(../../Themes/Images/'+ this.value+'.jpg)\"/></br>'+ this.axis.series[0].options.data[this.axis.categories.indexOf(this.value)];}",`

Comment: There's not difference between using two distinct variables and not using at all.. don't forget to accept the answer.